# Generate a output string, while rows dependent on another row in Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a problem in which rows in spark dataset are dependent on each other and i need to generate output string from Spark Dataset is as follows:

```
DataType    UniqueID    NameId  SurnameID    In2    In1
Double      12345       5       4            QQQ    BBB
Double      12345       6       5            BBB    RSA
Double      12345       4       3            RRR    QQQ
Double      12345       2       1            AAA    FFF
Double      12345       6       5            FRD    FG
Double      12345       7       6            FG     EXIT
Double      12345       1       0            NuLL   AAA
Double      12345       3       2            FFF    RRR
```

Output String: AAA, FFF, RRR, QQQ, BBB, RSA

Logic to generate output string is:

1. Group data on column UniqueID
2. Look for NuLL and AAA in columns In2 and In1 respectively. Both NuLL and AAA are entry point.
3. Now look for AAA in In2 column and look its NameId in SurnameID. If NameId matches its value in In1 column value, append In1 column value to resultant String.

For Eg: In1 Column is AAA and its  NameId column value is 1. Looking for  AAA in In2 column its In1 value is FFF and nameId of AAA i.e. 1 == SurnameID of In2. There for Append FFF to resultant string

4. Similarly repeat step 2, until no In1 column value is found in In2 column.
   If no value found terminate it and print output string

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is an edge table for a graph. Spark supports that in the GraphX component https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html

Comment: Thank you Arnon, This is really helpful.